# Getting Error in Asmx Web Service Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asmx

I am getting below error message while running unit test for ASMX web service

Failed `MyFunction` The ASP.NET Web application at 'D:\MyProjectFolder' is already configured for testing by another test run. Only one test run at a time can run tests in ASP.NET. If there are no other test runs using this Web application, ensure that the Web.config file does not contain an httpModule named HostAdapter.

I checked in web.config. Below line already added in web.config. i removed below line to run test again but getting same error message.

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="HostAdapter" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.HostAdapter.Web.HttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</httpModules>
```

i am not able to debug unit test project.

Comment: _"ensure that the Web.config file does ***not*** contain an httpModule named HostAdapter."_

Comment: i already removed it and try but still getting same error message.

Comment: Did it used to work, or did you just start testing? Are there multiple test projects?

Comment: I just started testing and its only single test project.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the corrupted Web.config with web.config.backup:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/904cedc5-894d-453d-b1a5-778a942e6f85/error-already-configured-for-testing-by-another-test-run?forum=vststest

Comment: its usually best to include the relevant part of a link in the question as links go out of date

Answer (score 0):

Just `comment` these tags:

```
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost(""]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost...")]
```

It worked for me after this.